# Is Mongo $currentDate subject to clock drift?

Tags: mongodb, synchronization, database-replication, sharding

I have a sharded and replicated MongoDB cluster and I was wondering when I use `$currentDate`, does MongoDB sync the current time between servers or may I experience substancial clock drifts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System clock synchronization is definitely outside the scope of responsibility of the MongoDB server.

[`$currentDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) will reflect the current time from the server's point-of-view when the document is updated, so clock drift in a sharded cluster will have an effect on `$currentDate` values if there are significant differences between shards.

If you are running any multiple server deployment you should always use a clock sync service (eg. NTP) to avoid potential clock drift. Generally services that make small, incremental adjustments to time (eg. `ntpd`) are preferable to utilities that make large adjustments (eg. `ntpdate`).

For more information on the potential outcomes of clock skew with MongoDB, see: [MongoDB and Leap Seconds](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-and-leap-seconds).